# How can I hide function arguments from php debug_print_backtrace

Tags: php

I want debug_print_backtrace to not print sensitive function arguments. My naive solution doesn't work.

```
<?php

function err ()
{
    debug_print_backtrace ();
}

function foo ($secret_arg, $arg)
{
    $arg = $secret_arg;
    $secret_arg = "<HIDDEN>";

    err ();
}

foo ("mysecret", 123);
?>
```

This outputs

```
#0  err() called at [/tmp/x.php:13]
#1  foo(mysecret, 123) called at [/tmp/x.php:16]
```

Even though I overwrote `$secret_arg` in the function, the backtrace shows it still contains `"mysecret"`.

But I **DO** still want any non-protected arguments to be shown in the trace.

Are there any non-hacky ways to hide this argument from the trace? From a design point of view, I really want the functions to locally know which arguments to protect, rather than writing a new backtrace function which knows where all the sensitive arguments are.

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP 5.3.6, you can simply do this:

```
debug_print_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php:

> DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS Whether or not to omit the "args" index,
>   and thus all the function/method arguments, to save memory.

Comment: I want to retain the arguments, just hide *some* of them.

Comment: Gotcha, not a problem; see my 2nd answer.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it:

```
function err()
{
    debug_print_backtrace();
}

function foo(&$secret_arg, $arg)
{
    $arg = $secret_arg;
    $secret_arg = "<HIDDEN>";

    err();
}

$secret = 'mysecret';

foo($secret, 123);
```

Prints:

```
#0  err() called at [/var/www/sites/portal.net2grid.com/test.php:32]
#1  foo(<HIDDEN>, 123) called at [/var/www/sites/portal.net2grid.com/test.php:37]
#2  require_once(/var/www/sites/portal.net2grid.com/test.php) called at [/var/www/sites/portal.net2grid.com/dispatch.php:73]
#3  __portal_dispatch() called at [/var/www/sites/portal.net2grid.com/dispatch.php:6]
```

What I did was I changed your `$secret_arg` argument so it's passed by reference.